# Laravel policy on route: Too few arguments to function 1 passed 2 expected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, policies

I've created a policy to guard my model. What I'm trying to do is block anyone from editing a thought record that isn't there's.

**web.php**

```
Auth::routes();

Route::prefix('/')->middleware(['auth','can:viewAny,App\ThoughtRecord'])->group(function() {

    Route::get('/record/{id}/edit', 'ThoughtRecordController@edit')->middleware('can:isOwner,App\ThoughtRecord');

    Route::patch('/record/{thoughtRecord}','ThoughtRecordController@update')->middleware('can:isOwner,App\ThoughtRecord');

});
```

**ThoughtRecordPolicy.php**

```
public function isOwner(User $user, ThoughtRecord $thoughtRecord)
{
    return $user->id == $thoughtRecord->user_id;

}
```

The `->middleware(['auth','can:viewAny,App\ThoughtRecord'])` works perfectly fine. The middleware on the other routes doesn't though `->middleware('can:isOwner,App\ThoughtRecord')` and produces this error:

**Error**

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
>   Too few arguments to function App\Policies\ThoughtRecordPolicy::isOwner(), 1 passed in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/thought-records/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php on line 706 and exactly 2 expected

**Edit:**

I changed the route to:

`Route::get('/record/{thoughtRecord}/edit', 'ThoughtRecordController@edit')->middleware('can:isOwner,thoughtRecord');`

Now I'm getting a 403 on a condition that I'm pretty positive is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're incorrectly passing second parameter to the `isOwner` policy's method.

The following should work:

```php
Route::get('/record/{thoughtRecord}/edit', 'ThoughtRecordController@edit')
   ->middleware('can:isOwner,thoughtRecord');
```

As per the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization#via-middleware):

> In this example, we're passing the can middleware two arguments. The first is the name of the action we wish to authorize and the second is the route parameter we wish to pass to the policy method. In this case, since we are using implicit model binding, a Post model will be passed to the policy method.

So you basically need to use implicit model binding and pass in the route parameter as the second argument.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. Oddly enough I just tried that. The problem I'm getting now is a 403 on a condition that is true.

Comment: Ideally it should not. It probably be because of the other middleware `can:viewAny`. Try remove that first and see where the problem is. Try return `true` from the `isOwner` in order to debug where the problem lies.

Comment: Ahhh wait. I just found out that the problem was on the @edit method on the controller it was passing `$id` as the parameter. Not `ThoughtRecord $thoughtRecord`. This works!